# iOS - selecting second lowest number in integer array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm, numbers

Let's say I have an array of numbers:

```
let numbers: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I want to pick out the second lowest number in that array but I don't want to use an index, I know you can pick the lowest and highest integer using min/maxElement dot notation so how would I get the second lowest or the second highest?

Comment: get Maxelement , remove it from array , again get max element?

Comment: @BhumitMehta how would I remove the item from the index without knowing which index it would be?

Comment: `var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; let min = numbers.minElement()!; let index = numbers.indexOf(min)!; numbers.removeAtIndex(index); let secondMin = numbers.minElement()!`

Comment: What do you expect for second lowest and second highest with `[1,1,2,3,4,4]`?

Comment: Or you can pass the array manually and remember the last two maximum items. The same algorithm can be extended using a k-heap to find the k-highest element in O(n + k) time.

Comment: @vacawama I would expect 1,1 and 4,4 thanks anyways your code helped.

Comment: How large is your array? For moderately sized arrays, sorting and picking the second element would be an option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A direct implementation: (as Sulthan suggested?)

```
func secondMax(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    let (_, second) = numbers.reduce((Int.min, Int.min)) {(max2: (first: Int, second: Int), value: Int) in
        if value > max2.first {
            return (value, max2.first)
        } else if value > max2.second {
            return (max2.first, value)
        } else {
            return max2
        }
    }
    return second
}
print(secondMax([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])) //->7
print(secondMax([1,1,2,3,4,4])) //->4
print(secondMax([5,5,6,1,2,3,4])) //->5
print(secondMax([5,6,6,1,2,3,4])) //->6
```

Answer (score 2):

As per OP comment that second max, min will be the max and min of array in case if redundancy. I have updated the approach.

```
var numbers: [Int] = [1,1,2,3,4,4] // or [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let maxCount = numbers.filter({$0 == numbers.max()}).count
let minCount = numbers.filter({$0 == numbers.min()}).count

let secondHighest = numbers.filter(){
    maxCount > 1 ? $0 == numbers.max() :  $0 < numbers.max()
}.last
// prints 4 for [1,1,2,3,4,4] and 7 for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

let secondLowest = numbers.filter(){
    minCount > 1 ? $0 == numbers.min() :  $0 > numbers.min()
}.first
// prints 1 for [1,1,2,3,4,4] and 2 for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: @vacawama updated to make it work with unsorted and duplicates element.

Comment: OP wants second lowest even if it is equal to lowest. I would recommend binging back your original answer and presenting it along with this one and explaining how they each solve a slightly different problem.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Find the lowest value; (2) Remove that value; (3) Find min of the remaining:

```
let numbers: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

var lowest = numbers.minElement()!
var secondLowest = numbers.filter { $0 > lowest }.minElement()
```

`secondLowest` is an optional because in case all values in your array are identical, there is really no "second lowest"

Answer (score 0):

// how to get the second lowest number in an integer Array

```
func secondLowest(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    let sortedArr = arr.sorted()
    return sortedArr[1]
}

print(secondLowest(arr: [1,8,100,4,5,6,7,2,212])) // 2
```